# Convert decimal value as reminder

Tags: algorithms, divisibility, decimal-expansion

I have a value of $26002$, after dividing it by $255$, it gives me $101.968627451$, but when I subtract $255$ from $26002$ repeatedly until I can't which left us with the reminder of $106$.

So my question is how can I convert $0.968627451$ to $106$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$255$ repeatedly subtracted from $26002$, until it is not possible, will give you a remainder of $247$, not $106$, which was suggested in the OP.

To convert a decimal number into an exact remainder, multiply the decimal number  by the divisor .

> $(0.968627451)$ x $(255) = 247$